# Is Lua's Local the same as VB's Dim?

Tags: vb.net, lua

Hello im trying to learn Lua and i dont know what Local is used for and i can not find a definition or a comparation with another language. So Is Lua's Local the same as VB's Dim ?

Answer (score 2):

The basic concept is very simple

```lua
function do_stuff()
   local a = 20
   b = 20
end

do_stuff()

print(a) --> nil
print(b) --> 20
```

As the example shows, `a` only exists within `do_stuff`, but "disappears" once that function finishes.

It gets more complicated if you consider closures though.

imagine this case:

```lua
function do_stuff
   local a = 20
   local f = function() return a end
   return f
end

print(a) --> nil
print(f()) --> 20
```

This seems like magic at first. After all, `a` should be gone, but `f()` still somehow finds it. This is because `f()` saves a references to `a` and keeps it alive. The *variable* `a` is still gone in a way, at least under that name.

---

To answer the original question though, no, they're really not the same thing at all.